# "RUN dotnet restore" fails while dockerizing ASP.Net Core 2.1 app

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-2.0

While trying to deploy my ASP.Net Core 2.1 app using [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application) article I'm stuck on the problem.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  25.18MB

Step 1/10 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS build-env
 ---> 625b44243fbe
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8c5d2ab76c0
Step 3/10 : COPY *.csproj ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c2c11e2b4699
Step 4/10 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 4ae02c24aabc
[91mDid you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
docker : The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 145
At D:\Projects\Ozon\solutionName\projectname\deploy.ps1:3 char:1
+ docker build -t projectname .
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The command '/b...-zero code: 145:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

There is the deploy script I'm running to dockerize my app.

```
docker build -t projectname .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name api projectname
```

There is my DOCKERFILE

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projectname.dll"]
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you're using `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime` instead `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk`. change the base image.

Comment: I think microsoft/aspnetcore-build is inappropriate, as it seems to contain only the 2.0 sdk instead of 2.1.

Comment: Yes, you're right, for 2.1 dotnet:2.1-sdk is the only appropriate to build the app. I corrected the answer, thanks.